# The AR malfunctions when I change tabs

Tags: swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I'm encountering an issue with ARView, where it seems to be malfunctioning when I switch between tabs in my application. I've implemented ARView in my project, and it works perfectly until I change tabs. When I return to the ARView tab, it appears to have trouble resuming properly. I've reviewed my code, and everything seems in order, but this behavior persists. I'm seeking assistance and any potential solutions or insights into what might be causing this issue.

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit
import RealityKit

struct TestTabView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 1
    @ObservedObject var arViewMode = ARViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack{
                Card(arView: arViewMode.arView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab1", systemImage: "house")
            }.tag(1)
            
            NavigationStack{
                ARViewTest(arView: arViewMode.arView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab1", systemImage: "arkit")
            }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Card: View {
    var arView: ARView
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink{
            ARViewContainer(arView: arView)
        }label: {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewTest: View {
    var arView: ARView
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer(arView: arView)
    }
}
```

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var arView: ARView
    @State private var arSessionError: Error?
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

class ARViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
}
```

I attempted to create two separate instances of ARViewContainer() to address the issue, but unfortunately, this approach didn't resolve the problem. Despite having two distinct ARView containers, the AR functionality still fails to work properly when switching between tabs in my application.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve it, but it should be `@StateObject var arViewMode = ARViewModel()` not `@ObservedObject`

Comment: `var arView: ARView` at `struct` level is bad practice, the `UIViewRepresentable` likes to maintain ownership inside the `makeUIView` `var arView: ARView` inside `Card` is likely being lost with redraws. Just a guess...